# CountDownTimer no se detiene

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
val counDown = object : CountDownTimer(7000, 7000){
        override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
            switchChecked(mapWords)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            this.start()
        }

    }
    btncounterD.setOnClickListener {
        counDown.start()
    }
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
        counDown.cancel()
    }
```

Tengo un CountDownTimer el cual imprime un Toast, este CountDownTimer funciona como un bucle el cual se inicia al presionar un botón y a su vez se cancela cuando presiono otro botón. Todo funciona correctamente en la misma Activity sin embargo al momento de pasar a otra activity y volver a la anterior e intentar cancelar el bucle, ya no se cancela y el bucle continua y no se detiene a menos de que cierre la aplicación. Les agradezco de antemano por sus consejos y su atención.

Comment: Hola, agrega por favor en donde creas el CountDownTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Para cancelar el conteo del `CountDownTimer`, simplemente se debe llamar a **[.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer#cancel())**:

```
counDown.cancel()
```

lo anterior debería funcionar sin problema, **me parece que lo que esta pasando es que estas creando otra instancia de `CountDownTimer`**, asegura que no tengas la creación del `CountDownTimer` en onResume() o algo en tu código que cree una instancia nueva al regresar a la activity.

Comment: El CountDownTimer se crea en el onCreate() únicamente.  Por ejemplo yo presiono el botón que inicia al counDown y cambio de activity aun con el counDown ejecutándose y regreso para cancelarlo, ya no puedo hacerlo y queda así a menos de que cierre la aplicación.

Comment: Ok, entonces cuando sales de esta activity y cambias a otra la finalizas? por ejemplo usas finish() ?

Comment: No la finalizo al cambiar de activity debido a que necesito que siga su funcionamiento.